# How can I compare my PHPASS-hashed stored password to my incoming POST data?

Tags: php

Here's a better example, just a simple checking..stored value in database has password: fafa (hashed with phpass in registration) and username: fafa; i am using the phpass password hashing framework

```
public function demoHash($data) //$data is the post data named password
{

    $hash =new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $query = ORM::factory('user');
    $result = $query
        ->select('username, password')
        ->where('username', 'fafa')
        ->find();
    $hashed = $hash->HashPassword($data);
    $check = $hash->CheckPassword($hashed, $result->password);
    echo $result->username . "<br/>";
    echo $result->password . "<br/>";
    return $check;
}
```

check is returning false

Answer (score 2):

Right now your `$hash` variable is declared local to the register() function. You need to move it outside both functions and use `global $hash` inside each to scope it properly, or initialize it separately in both functions as a local variable.

Edit: Modifications to your updated code below.

```
public function demoHash($data) //$data is the post data named password
{

        $hash =new PasswordHash(8, false);
        $query = ORM::factory('user');
        $result = $query
                ->select('username, password')
                ->where('username', 'fafa')
                ->find();
        //$hashed = $hash->HashPassword($data);
        $check = $hash->CheckPassword($data, $result->password);
        echo $result->username . "<br/>";
        echo $result->password . "<br/>";
        return $check;
}
```

Don't pass a hashed input to the first argument of CheckPassword - it's designed to do the hashing on its own.

Comment: i've updated the code...i now have them in a function that handles incoming data...look at the update

Comment: You don't pass a hashed value to the first argument of CheckPassword() - you pass the plaintext of the user's input and CheckPassword automatically hashes it for you. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: still not working, removed the line you just removed...still getting a false

Comment: Try echoing out both `$result->password` and the value returned from `HashPassword($data)` and compare them yourself. Perhaps something's up with logic outside of phpass itself?

Comment: tried doing that. tried for 6 times, phpass generated a different value for HashPasswod($data) each time

Answer (score 0):

Your hashing algorithm should return the same hash when given the same password.  Therefore, running HashPassword on the POSTed data should ALWAYS equal the hash saved in the database.

Hash the POSTed password with the same function and compare to the previously saved hash.

Comment: tried what u said...not working...examined the hashed post data...tried to enter the same password for 4 times...they all produced different hashes...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough info here to determine the problem- lets see if we can clarify a few things- I'll add some values and you let me know if the flow is correct:

```
function register()
{
// register user
$hash = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);// hash = abcd1234
$hashed = $hash->HashPassword($hash);// hashed = DF431268

//register logic here
}

function login()
{
// login user
$data = $_POST['password']; // data = abcd1234
$password = // query password here // password = DF431268
$check = $hash->CheckPassword($data, $password); // assuming this function hashes $data through the same $hash->HashPassword($hash) function previously and then returns true if they are the same, check should be true...
return $check // check is returning false!
}
```

can you post the CheckPassword method of your hash class?

Comment: You can find the entire class here: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/phpass-0.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $result->password is already hashed, try this:

```
$check = $hash->CheckPassword($data, $result->password);
```

Or even this:

```
$check = $hash->HashPassword($data) === $result->password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with CheckPassword() and the problem was actually with my database: the password field was not long enough for storing the entire hashed password.

Seeing the examples phpass comes with, I setted my field password to **60 characters length** and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just one warning: Two hashes of the same identical password **ARE NOT EQUAL**.

```
$h = new PasswordHash (8, False);

var_dump ($h->HashPassword('pikachu123') == $h->HashPassword('pikachu123'));
```

You will obtain:

```
bool(false)
```

That is because the `HashPassword` creates a different [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) everytime you hash a string. So comparing a hashed version of your incoming password with the one saved in your database **will not work**.

That's why exists the `CheckPassword` function, who internally hashes your clean password using the salt from the already hashed string.